# Why are all single words in php strings

Tags: php

So I came across this feature/bug today and I'm struggling to wrap my head around what is going on.

so we all know that in php this:

```
echo 'hello';
print 'world';
echo gettype('test');
```

will return this:

```
hello
world
string
```

However, until today I was unaware that this:

```
echo hello;
print world;
echo gettype(hello);
```

will return this:

```
hello
world
string
```

What is going on here?  What is happening in php's compilation process that it sees any single word as a string?  Does this have a name? Does it have any utility?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are not wrapping a piece of "string" inside quotes (be it double or single), the interpreter will try to make a guess and cast that into a String. I believe when you run that piece of PHP in error_reporting(E_ALL) you will see a notice

```
Notice: Use of undefined constant string - assumed 'string' in Command line code on line 1
```

A good practice is to always turn on error_reporting to E_ALL in development setups, but remember to turn it to less descriptive in production, you don't want people to have access to sensitive information (such as path) if your php errors out.

Comment: ok, follow up:  why does php "guess" that the word should be string?  The only languages I could find that don't raise something like this as a syntax error are languages like ruby and python where variable indicators aren't used.  Is this just another case of PHP being lazy?

Comment: Depends on how you look at it, some people regard this as "programmer-friendly" feature. But I'd say writing good code is still a programmer's responsibility and mindset, we shouldn't rely too much on interpreter to tell us when there might be a problem with our code. Also the fact that if you set error_reporting to E_ALL throws you a warning is a good indication that php is not so much of being lazy (there's checking in place, it's not completely ignored)

Answer (score 7):

If PHP can't find a function or constant by the name of `hello`, then yes, it treats it as a string.  However, this is bad practice, and is even warned against:

```
>php -r 'error_reporting(E_ALL|E_STRICT);echo gettype(blah);'
PHP Notice:  Use of undefined constant blah - assumed 'blah' in Command line code on line 1
```

So, the moral of the story is to **always** turn on `error_reporting` in PHP (just like you should **always** `use strict` and `use warnings` in Perl).